# php/mysql question, retrieving information

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question, pretty new at PHP and MySql

but was curious is it possible to display only the most recent column to a table, from a database?

I know it is possible to display a list of all information, or if you have just one column of information in your table to display that using the

Here is my code for my basic script (just loads 1 column of information)   I would like it to only print out the recent column i added to the table

```
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die ('Could not connect:' . mysql_error()0;
}
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);
$result = mysql_query(Select column FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['column'];
}

mysql_close($con);
```

*** keep in mind, im not looking for someone to shoot me my code with it completed, though it would be handy, however just giving me the options of what I have to do, or what the script is called would be plentiful enough for my research, thanks!

Comment: Please format your code so that others may find it more friendly. You also have some code that was filtered out by SO.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the most recent row there are several options, but if you have an auto-increment ID value (a lot of my tables do...), you can simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add a timestamp column to your table, ORDER BY the timestamp and [LIMIT](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) the result set.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch the most recent data from only 1 column then I believe the following code will help (id should be in order. it would be good if auto increment is set):

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```